# Using SQL Query to Define min/max for Random_int

Tags: php, mysql, random

I am trying to use a SQL query to define min/max values for the radnom_int function.

```
private function doPreEventStart($user) {
    $MaxResult = db_fetch_item("SELECT max(resultid) FROM ResultPackage
      where ResultPackage.slotid like ‘%{$slot_id}'
      and ResultPackage.PackageID like '%{$user->packageid}%'
      ORDER BY resultid asc LIMIT 1")
    $MinResult = db_fetch_item("SELECT min(resultid) FROM ResultPackage
        where ResultPackage.slotid like ‘%{$slot_id}'
        and ResultPackage.PackageID like '%{$user->packageid}%'
        ORDER BY resultid asc LIMIT 1")
     $this->curResultId =  var_dump(random_int($MinResult,$MaxResult)
    }
```

So far this has not worked and I get the following errors when I try to run the file.

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in /var/www/html/VC/server-vc-RNG.php on line 761
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /var/www/html/VC/server-vc-RNG.php on line 762
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /var/www/html/VC/server-vc-RNG.php on line 762
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$MinResult' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/VC/server-vc-RNG.php on line 757
```

Please help me see the error.

Comment: You're missing `;` at the end of each PHP statement.

Comment: There's no need to use two queries. `SELECT MIN(resultid) AS minresult, MAX(resultid) AS maxresult FROM ...`

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in your queries. Turn off "smart quotes" when editing code.

Comment: Where do you set the variable `$slot_id`. It's not a function parameter, and it's not declared `global $slot_id;`.

Comment: Which line is 761? The error says there's an unexpected `;`, but that character doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: `var_dump()` doesn't return anything. Why are you assigning the result of `var_dump()` to a variable? You should assign the result of `random_int()` to the variable, and then do `var_dump($this->curResultId);`. Also, you have unbalanced parentheses on that line.

Comment: `ORDER BY resultid LIMIT 1` is not needed. The query only returns one row because it has no `GROUP BY`, so there's nothing to order.

Comment: You appear to be using smartquotes `‘` . Please don't use Word for formatting code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaned up parathesis and incorrect quotation marks:

```
private function doPreEventStart($user) {
    $MaxResult = db_fetch_item("SELECT max(resultid) FROM ResultPackage
      where ResultPackage.slotid like '{$this->curSlotId}'
      and ResultPackage.PackageID like '%{$user->packageid}%'
      LIMIT 1");
    $MinResult = db_fetch_item("SELECT min(resultid) FROM ResultPackage
        where ResultPackage.slotid like '{$this->curSlotId}'
        and ResultPackage.PackageID like '%{$user->packageid}%'
        LIMIT 1");
    $this->curResultId =  var_dump(random_int($MinResult,$MaxResult));
   }
```

Creates a new error:

```
Call to undefined function random_int()
```